# exist of k-critical graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

In the graph theory we have this theorem:
[image]

my question is why exist subgraph $H^\prime$ ?,in every graph $G$ with $\chi(G)=k$ has k-critical subgraph  $H$ ?

Comment: what's definition of $\delta(H)$ ?

Comment: Minimum degree of every vertx

Comment: What happens if there isn't a k-critical subgraph?  That would imply that each time you delete an edge or a vertex that you *still* cannot successfully color with $\chi(G)-1$ or fewer colors.  Note that there are a finite number of edges and vertices, if you delete enough then you are left with graphs which can trivially be colored with 1 color (e.g. graph with no edges)... contradiction.